Asp.net MVC Getting Paypal Access Token in Live Mode
I used the following code to get a Paypal token in Sandbox mode, it works fine.  However, switching the Live produces not code.
private string GetPaypalAccessToken()
{
string accessToken = "";
string url = PaypalUrl + "/v1/oauth2/token";

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    string credentials64 =
        Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PaypalClientId + ":" + PaypalSecret));

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials64);

    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
    requestMessage.Content = new StringContent("grant_type=client_credentials", null, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    var responseTask = client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
    responseTask.Wait();

    var result = responseTask.Result;
    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        readTask.Wait();

        var strResponse = readTask.Result;

        var jsonResponse = JsonNode.Parse(strResponse);
        if (jsonResponse != null)
        {
            accessToken = jsonResponse["access_token"]?.ToString() ?? "";
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("JWT: " + accessToken);
return accessToken;

I've tried following the response given in 'How to get access token from PayPal in MVC' a couple of years ago but it is so different from the code I've used I cannot figure out how to modify the above.  Can someone give me a simple guide to how to do this?  Yes,I have changed the url in appsetting.json to "https://api-m.paypal.com/"
